# change in the User object Or java object and affect on Redis cached data

Tags: java, redis

I have data for User objects that is currently stored Redis.

I added more attributes to the User object.

I want to deploy the change to the web application servers.

is Redis going to remove the old objects and build new objects ?

What steps I can take so that current Users objects don't get affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I learned a lesson. I have two app servers which were accessing the redis cache. When I deployed changes. One server got new code and another had old code during the deploy process. So for some user objets there was a mismatch and user objects completely got removed from cache. In cases when redis cache is used by more then one server all server needs to go down first. update all of them and then bring all of them back again.